# Disable jQuery Mobile Source Maps

Tags: jquery-mobile, source-maps

Although source maps are great for debugging, you don't really need to be sending these files to your end users. jQuery Mobile's source map is huge (222 kb, which is massive for a mobile website). Is there some way of disabling the request to get this map from the server? I have tried using jQuery's CDN and tried using a local include, but in both cases a request is visible in the Network tab of Chrome's DevTools.